# Can't properly fit images inside my table

Tags: tables, graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

The following LaTeX code generates a table with images, but it's not centralized with the paper:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float, longtable}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{changepage}    


\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{table}[h]
            \begin{tabular}{ |p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
                \hline
                    \begin{figure}[H]
                    \begin{center}
                    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{graf1.png}
                    \caption{}
                    \end{center}
                    \end{figure}
                    &
                    \begin{figure}[H]
                    \begin{center}  
                    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{graf1.png}
                    \caption{}
                    \end{center}
                    \end{figure}\\
                \hline
                    \begin{figure}[H]
                    \begin{center}
                    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{graf1.png}
                    \caption{}
                    \end{center}
                    \end{figure}
                    &
                    \begin{figure}[H]
                    \begin{center}
                    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{graf1.png}
                    \caption{}
                    \end{center}
                    \end{figure}\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

I've tried using smaller numbers for `\begin{tabular}{ |p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}`, but the table doesn't change. Also, I've tried using other packages like `\usepackage{lscape}`, `\usepackage{longtable}` and `\usepackage{rotating}`, but I didn't want to rotate my table or make it occupy the entire page. Could someone help me?

Comment: please see if the answer meets the requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions and comments:

- Never, ever, embed a `figure` or `table` enviroment in a `center` environment. Nothing good will come of it.
- Are you serious about setting the usable column widths to merely `1cm`? In the code below, I've set the column widths to `3cm`.
- Your code, which uses `table`, `figure`, *and* multiple `center` environment, is needlessly complicated. I suggest using a single `figure` environment, a single `\centering` instruction, and a single `tabular` environment.
- Observe that it's possible to have multiple `\caption` directives in a single `figure` environment.
- I've kept the vertical rules and `\hline` directives that were in your code. However, I don't think they're necessary, let alone helpful. In fact, they're simply distracting and ugly. I'd omit them if this were my document...

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
%% I've commented out the instructions that don't affect the look of the graphs
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{float, longtable}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating} % load 'graphicx' package automatically
%\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{changepage}    


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
      \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{graf1.png}
      \caption{\dots}
    &
      \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{graf2.png}
      \caption{\dots}
    \\
    \hline
      \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{graf3.png}
      \caption{\dots}
    &
      \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{graf4.png}
      \caption{\dots}
    \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow.. that was clean! Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=2ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{XX}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./img/1.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure A}\label{fig:taba}
            &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./img/1.png}   
            \captionof{figure}{Figure B}\label{fig:tabb}              \\
            
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{./img/1.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure C}\label{fig:tabc}
            &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./img/1.png} 
            \captionof{figure}{Figure D}\label{fig:tabd}
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{A table with figures}
        \label{tab:mytable}
    \end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. For the third figure, though, i'd change `width=0.45\columnwidth` to `width=\linewidth`.